# Can't update data in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, google-maps

I am trying to update lat and long from the user entered address using google maps API in node.js and then use it in google maps to display the location. But my data is not updating

I'm including the put route here.

```
 router.put("/:id", isSafe, function(req, res){
  request('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?key=my_key&address=' + encodeURIComponent(req.body.address), function (err, response, body) {
   if (err){
      console.log('error!', err);
      res.redirect("back");
    } else {
    var data = JSON.parse(body);
    var lat = data.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
    var lng = data.results[0].geometry.location.lng;
    var address = data.results[0].formatted_address;
    var newData = {address : address , lat: lat, lng: lng};
    Campground.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, {$set: newData},req.body.campground, function(err, campground){
if(err){  

     req.flash("error", err.message);
            res.redirect("back");
        } else {
            req.flash("success","Successfully Updated!");
            res.redirect("/campgrounds/" + campground._id);
        }
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine to me. It works as well. What I did not understand is about your data not reaching the template. Can you explain about that?

What template are we talking about?

Comment: The code I have here is a part of server-side right, so I need to send the data stored in the database to frontend so i can display it.
I was referring to the front end part as template.